# Is it a Cactus?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, graph-theory

In graph theory, a [Cactus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cactus_graph) is a connected graph such that any distinct two simple cycles in the graph share at most one vertex.

Here is a Cactus with 3 simple cycles outlined with dashed lines.

[image: Cactus Graph]

The following graph is similar to the one pictured above but is not a Cactus because the two vertices labeled in red are shared by two simple cycles.

[image: Not Cactus Graph]

Things can get a little bit trickier, for example the following graph:

[image: Also not a Cactus graph]

Might look like a Cactus but it is not.  This can be shown by highlighting the following cycle:

[image: Highlighted cycle]

This cycle shares more than one point with a lot of the more obvious cycles in the graph.

#### Definitions

- A connected graph is a graph such that there exists at least one path between any two vertices.
- A simple cycle is a path on a graph that starts and ends at the same vertex and visits no vertex more than once.
- A simple graph is an undirected, unweighted graph such that no vertices are connected two each other by more than one edge and no vertex is connected to itself.  A simple graph is the most basic type of graph and is what most people mean when they say graph.

## Task

Take a simple graph as input and decide whether it is a Cactus graph.  You should output two distinct values one for True and one for False.  You may take input in any format you see fit.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so you should aim to minimize the byte count of your answers.

[Test Cases](https://gist.github.com/Wheatwizard/5cbaf2b496f40d7be4aade412f25153a)

[Test Cases as Adjacency Matrices](https://gist.github.com/Wheatwizard/d147308c59ca9e38477eccdbddeabf10)

Comment: What complexity class does this problem belong to?

Answer (score 10):

## Mathematica, 62 bytes

```
Sort@#==#⋃#&[Join@@FindCycle[#,∞,All]]&&ConnectedGraphQ@#&
```

Checks: `(find all cycles, there are no duplicate edges)` and `(The graph is a connected graph)`

Comment: `g` should be `#`, right?

Comment: So you're telling me there's no `isCactus` builtin? I'm disappointed.

Comment: Someone should write one.

Comment: You should put Mathematica Simplified as a separate answer.

Comment: @Aaron It would be `CactusQ` if it existed, I believe.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>299</s> 289 bytes

```python
j=input()
n=len(j)
Q=range(n*n)
L=N=[[{1<<i%n|1<<i/n}]*j[i/n][i%n]for i in Q]
for _ in Q:N=[[a|b for A,B in zip(N[i/n::n],N[i%n::n])for a in A for b in B if{1}>a&b]for i in Q];L=[L[i]+N[i]for i in Q]
1/all(L[i]*all(A&B|B&C|C&A for A in L[i]for B in L[i]for C in L[i])for i in Q if i%n<i/n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVVhb9owEP2eX2FlGkpoRJJqtFPWTIK2TJMQW9V9WhZVAUxrltqRbZqy0t/Ozg6EsJKBtn1YhMjL3b2792wHsrm8Y/R4KbGQAoUoMhBclv5WV1Qi/eQ5yIdP7GyHIebtDqtMJVyBX/gMF0@2s3/oromH9o1WsoGwlqqht4KAe0kq8CE6Xjiq@q9fgh2Znd0qUEs6fIHWc@q11STrtXsVZn3yX@1wqXGfhz02duW3nNSa2Wf2v/Xr7/Hr/Znfnfy/8Fvv1Putxnp1h7w5sWHgRzy6EZITegs/caZpLqchodlMWrZBwxRTa2obVyFP6C22aJPaRj8chFH05J@dkdd0oW4ufY6b0wjucQSxeMI4IohQdBUbCt9oHChashgiFeo4XRX8QTJroIhBQGNnoNgK2aokUQUdXT1UEAiTJ//5fdIYVie864dRPyLxEbC3JvtukqaWSjUV6DS6i27jfHHeKHp2VFl/xelWH87XD/amHcxGIE55tZewSsYrdDm4QB8@9XsG4GtyP0sTiZGQYyjXvNUikvuMcYmYcJCYC1V8J2UmAtcVMhl9Zw@YT1KWt0bs3k1cv@212yfHJ@7pm7d@2z81uINy2BgmWhnJsNoUnN8UU3R0MmYZbBKUmdy0DZaOi6ye1loXlthBJd/Itzrk0CGHDnrpx1On2DX93xfo85K3ck4ktjjOuAUVNjpC5jcKFBCfMqHEbdj4McMjice/NJF8HpSHUZ09q3IA7TLDsZilEvSp98goakc4k@gr5uyCPBBBGL3knPHgJUefcR2GTVtHw1LRhpHBUGmZnzvX12YxGwPzRb7X@djfGDI3EFZsOJPolkkIFoPs5U8) (simulates STDIN to run all test cases at once)

*-10 bytes thanks to @ovs*

Takes input as an adjacency matrix from STDIN.

Outputs by the presence of an error in accordance with [a default output method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11908/68261). An IndexError represents non-cactus, and no error represents cactus.

### Theory

A simple cycle can be thought of as two disjoint simple paths between a pair of vertices. Similarly, our conjoined cycles correspond to three distinct simple paths being present between a pair of vertices (better explanation near the bottom of the ungolfed code).

To detect these conjoined cycles, we:

- find all paths between all pairs of vertices, keeping track of the edges using Python sets.
- for each pair of vertices, if three paths are pairwise disjoint, then a conjoined cycle is present.

The first bullet has the side-benefit of making the connectedness easy to test: if a path exists between every pair of distinct vertices, then the graph is connected.

### Potential improvements

If input could be taken via STDIN as `n` followed by `n*n` rows of boolean values, 13 bytes could be saved, but it doesn't feel right.

A lot of generator for-loop code is repeated, so surely there's a better way. I tried `itertools.product`, but that ended up with a net cost of +9 bytes. I might have to go with exec/string-replacement abuse like in [Baba](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206476/68261), which could especially help with `for i in Q` being used four times.

### Ungolfed Code

Python 2 has two main benefits over Python 3 here:

- `input()` automatically parses the input
- Division is floor division by default.

```python
j = input()
n = len(j)
Q = range(n * n)
# Replace each 0 in the adjacency matrix with []
#   and each edge with a label such that the element of N representing the edge m→n has the
#   same label as the element of N representing the edge n→m
L = N = [
    # Each edge label is a 2-hot integer (easiest way to ensure ensure equality in both directions since the graph is undirected)
    # Each path's edge sequence is stored as a set of edge labels
    # N[i] is a list of paths from vertex i % n to vertex i / n
    # N[i] starts out as all possible paths of length 1, i.e. edges
    # L[i] starts as the same
    [{1 << i%n | 1 << i/n}]
    * j[i / n][i % n]
    for i in Q
]

# Repeat this n**2 times:
# (In reality, only about log_2(n) times is needed, but there isn't a big performance loss)
for _ in Q:
    # Update N from the list of all possible paths of length k to the list of all possible paths of length k+1
    N = [
        [
            # The union of two paths is possible
            a | b
            # ... for every paths list in N
            for A, B in zip(N[i / n :: n], N[i % n :: n])
            # ... and for every pair of paths in each of these paths lists
            for a in A
            for b in B
            # Limit the search to be through disjoint paths only
            # equivalent to `{1}>a&b == not a&b` because a,b contain only tuples, not integers
            if {1} > a & b
        ]
        for i in Q
    ]
    # Update L from being list of all possible paths of length at most k to the list of all possible paths of length at most k+1
    # (It really seems like these two generator for-loops can be merged into one for loop, but I couldn't get it to work
    #  I might be able to store L and N in the same list, but that's super slow performance; hard to test)
    L = [L[i] + N[i] for i in Q]
# Raises a ZeroDivisionError iff the result of the `all` call is False
1/all(
    # L[i] is falsey ←→ L[i] is an empty list ←→
    # no path exists between vertices i%n and i/n ←→ graph is not connected ←→ not cactus
    L[i]
    * all(
        # `A & B | B & C | C & A` is falsey
        # → A,B,C are three disjoint simple paths between vertices i%n and i/n
        # → AB' and CB' are two cycles that share an edge
        # → The graph is non-cactus
        A & B | B & C | C & A
        # using itertools.product is net +9 bytes last I checked
        for A in L[i]
        for B in L[i]
        for C in L[i]
    )
    for i in Q
    # L is symmetric, and we don't want to check the main diagonal
    if i % n < i / n
)
```

### Super-ungolfed code

```python
def dot(r1, r2):
    return [
        path1 | path2
        for paths1, paths2 in zip(r1, r2)
        for path1 in paths1
        for path2 in paths2
        # simple paths, so exclude those that share edges
        if len(path1 & path2) == 0
    ]


def mul(paths1, paths2):
    return [[dot(row, col) for row in zip(*paths2)] for col in paths1]


def f(adj):
    n = len(adj)
    paths_length_1 = [
        [
            [{(min(x, y), max(x, y))}] if entry == 1 else []
            for x, entry in enumerate(row)
        ]
        for y, row in enumerate(adj)
    ]
    all_paths = paths_length_1
    paths_length_n = paths_length_1
    for _ in range(n):
        paths_length_n = mul(paths_length_1, paths_length_n)
        for y in range(n):
            for x in range(n):
                all_paths[y][x].extend(paths_length_n[y][x])
    for x, row in enumerate(all_paths):
        for y, paths in enumerate(row):
            # The graph is non-cactus if it is not conneted
            if x != y and len(paths) == 0:
                return False
            # The graph is non-cactus if there exist three piecewise disjoint simple paths A,B,C
            # between two nodes because A+B' forms one cycle and C+B' forms the other cycle
            for A, B, C in itertools.combinations(paths, 3):
                if len(A & B) == 0 and len(B & C) == 0 and len(A & C) == 0:
                    return False
    return True
```

Comment: I think `frozenset([i%n,i/n])` can be replaced by `1<<i%n|1<<i/n`, and if you flip error/non-error `1/...` is a bit shorter than `[0][...]`

Comment: @ovs Added. And I must say, great idea with the two-hot integer

Comment: I just recently used this on my Erdős–Woods answer, but to save memory and time instead of bytes. Otherwise I wouldn't have seen it, it's definitely a bit unusual

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 130 bytes

```javascript
f=(x,y,h)=>x.every(h=(c,i,g)=>!g||h([c[1],c[0]],i)?eval(y)-c[0]||f(x.filter(_=>i--),y+[,c]):0)>/(,\d+,).*(,\d+),.*\1.*\2$/.test(y)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jYzRioMwEEXf/YoW@jBjx9jEPu0S90PSsEhMNIvoolYU/Hc37dK@tnOYy3C4zE8xFYPp/e@YtF1pt81JmGmhGmU@MzvZfoFagiFPVVD7al1rUEZxTUadtCaPX3YqGlgwuYl1dTAz55vR9vAtc58kSMtRkdH4ccI8BbqUR0IW3w8kFl94WHFI2WiHMfzZPndpHF3b0jrf2pIE8UAWEIFzIIt2z5HPlA8TxWlkunboGsuargIHSnESmpSgLGRGXGvEF53zW53/bzdz729/)

Finds a path through `a,b,a,b`

`y` has form `undefined,1,2` therefore `eval(y)` gets the last value in `y`

Comment: Didn't notice requirement of connection

Answer (score 2):

## [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), with IGraph/M, 9 bytes

```mathematica
IGCactusQ
```

IGraph/M provides a Mathematica interface to the popular igraph network analysis package. You can use `IGCactusQ` function in  `` IGraphM` ``  package.

```mathematica
Needs["IGraphM`"];
IGCactusQ[g]
```

---

Ungolfed version of [@JungHwan Min's Mathematica answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120620/110802).

```mathematica
Clear["Global`*"];
g = Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
   3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 
   3 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 
   6 \[UndirectedEdge] 7, 7 \[UndirectedEdge] 8, 
   8 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 7 \[UndirectedEdge] 9, 
   9 \[UndirectedEdge] 10, 10 \[UndirectedEdge] 11, 
   11 \[UndirectedEdge] 7, 8 \[UndirectedEdge] 12, 
   8 \[UndirectedEdge] 13}, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
  GraphLayout -> "SpringElectricalEmbedding"]

myCactusGraphQ[graph_] := 
 Module[{cycles, noDuplicateEdges },
  cycles = FindCycle[graph, \[Infinity], All]; (*Find all cycles in the graph, with no limit on their length *)
  noDuplicateEdges = DuplicateFreeQ[Join@@cycles];
  noDuplicateEdges && ConnectedGraphQ[graph] (*Finally, check that the graph is connected AND the noDuplicateEdges condition is met*)
] 

Print["myCactusGraphQ[g]=", myCactusGraphQ[g]]
```

[image]